# preventing hands going through floor

Tags: animation

I'm really hoping someone can help - been stuck for months now. I'm completely new to blender and animation in general. I've managed to find a pre-rigged model online - I want to create an exercise animation using the model - while the feet dont go through the floor when animating; the hands do for example when trying to create a push up animation. Is there anyway to get round this? I am completely new to all of this so any help with simple instructions would be much appreciated. I would have attached the blender file - but dont think you can on here.

Comment: you can use https://pasteall.org/blend/ if you want to upload a blend file

Answer (score 1):

Blend file below...

[image]

A lot may depend on how your rig is set up but placing Empties as 'ik targets', (not pole targets) at limb extremities does lend itself to this sort of thing quite well. By that I mean hand and foot targets as against lower arm and leg.  The hand targets are simply placed on the floor, the feet versions placed where they're needed.

[image]

For push-ups, some upper-arm Quatemion adjustments (pose mode) will likely be necessary due to extreme bending at the joints.

The character's origin point needs to be set at the feet so the armature can be rotated from there -

Once the first push-up is done, it's a simple matter of either duplication in the Dopesheet or cycling the action.

A "Nav"(igation) handle, an Empty would also be placed at the OP and the armature and targets parented to that.  This would hold it all together and provide a 'handle' with which to drag the whole thing about -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While I am no expert, it strikes me that when posing a rigged character you are completely in control of where things are placed.  Perhaps I am a little confused about your problem.  I am pretty sure you are able to post a blend file of at least a link to it.

Comment: thanks Mark. What i mean is for example, if the model is standing up - and you move the middle part of the body downwards - the feet stay where they are and the model squats down as the legs bend. However if say the model is in a plank position - and you move the middle part of the body down towards the mat - the hands go through the mat (floor) - essentially I want the arms to bend automatically (like the legs) when you move the model down. Its quite hard to explain - I'm hoping this is a bit clearer. I cant see anywhere to add the file - but will look more.

Comment: This may sound silly but when the hands go through the floor, you should be able to move the hands only back up to where you want them.  Then you press i to keyframe that position.